# Code replaces table headers and will not merge rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am sorting this table by metric tons per hour, and the code I have so far deletes the headers(the second row down is just shifted up) and I can't figure out how to make this not happen. Also, I want to merge the cells in the far left column once the list is sorted so different number ranges are grouped off rather than stating the range in each row. I need the ranges  to be 6-8, 10-15, 16-21, 24-28. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub SystemSize()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim I As Long, Groups As Long

Range("A2:I" & LastRow).Sort key1:=Range("I2"), order1:=xlAscending 'Sorts data

Groups = 1


Do While Groups < 8
 I = 2
Select Case Groups
  Case 1


    For j = 2 To LastRow

        If Cells(j, 9) >= 6 And Cells(j, 9) <= 8 Then
            Cells(j, 1) = "6-8 MTPH" 'Cells(j, 1)
             I = I + 1
        End If
    Next
Case 2


    For j = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 10 And Cells(j, 9) <= 15 Then
            Cells(j, 1) = "10-15 MTPH"
             I = I + 1
        End If
    Next

Case 3


    For j = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 16 And Cells(j, 9) <= 21 Then
            Cells(j, 1) = "16-21 MTPH"
             I = I + 1
        End If
    Next

Case 4

    For j = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 24 And Cells(j, 9) <= 28 Then
            Cells(j, 1) = "24-28 MTPH"
             I = I + 1
        End If
    Next

Case 5

    For j = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 30 And Cells(j, 9) <= 38 Then
            Cells(j, 1) = "30-38 MTPH"
        End If
    Next

Case 6

    For j = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 40 And Cells(j, 9) <= 48 Then
            Cells(j, 1) = "40-48 MTPH"
             I = I + 1
        End If
    Next

Case 7 'this added to pick up data that does not fall into a group, like 8 or 9
   For j = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) > 0 And Cells(j, 9) < 6 Or Cells(j, 9) > 48 Then
            Cells(j, 1) = "No Group"
             I = I + 1
        End If
    Next

End Select

Groups = Groups + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: why don't you try recording a macro where you merge a few cells together, and then using that code to modify this macro?

Comment: When I do this with a macro, excel records the merge with cell reference numbers. I need the code to merge rows if they are all in the same size group. I can't do this using numbers because more items will be added to the list over time.

Comment: Everything in your code uses dynamic references (e.g., `Cells(j,9)` etc.)  You seem familiar enough with the cells & worksheet object to do this, so surely using the macro recorder to learn how the `Merge` method works is not too difficult.  I'm trying to point you in the right direction so that you can solve this on your own :)

Comment: I'm very new to the VBA language(about 3 days in), but I am experienced with MATlab programming. So basically I know pretty much what I want to do, but I have no idea on the syntax and how to go about it. I need to get the indices for the first and last cell for each size section and merge using these indices. Wanna help write that bad boy out?

Comment: Looking at this script, appears the data is already *sorted* so that the groups are basically together already, right? All that's left is to merge the cells in column A, based on the value of the cells in column A?

Comment: Correct. The only thing left is the merge. And the amount of cells with the same values in column A to be merged is subject to change(why a loop of some sort comparing values would be needed I believe)

Answer (score 1):

the sort parameter should have an option to specify `Header=xlYes` or similar

```
Range("A2:I" & LastRow).Sort key1:=Range("I2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:= xlYes 'Sorts data
```

Comment: I am very new to the VBA language(I was helped with the code I provided), could you help me with the syntax on how to write this parameter in?

Comment: Ok I've got the headers fixed, now I just need to get this merging down. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you with the merge.

Before your `End Sub`, add the following line to call another procedure:

```
MergeTableRows lastRow
```

Then, add this subroutine, which should do the merging in Column A, based on like values.

```
Sub MergeTableRows(lastRow As Long)
Dim fullRange As Range
Dim firstCell As Range
Dim x As Integer 'cell counter
Dim rngToMerge As Range

    Set fullRange = Range("A2:I" & lastRow)

    x = 1
    Do
        If firstCell Is Nothing Then Set firstCell = fullRange.Cells(x, 1)

            'Determine how many cells by counting the number of like occurrences '
            countCells = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf( _
                    fullRange.Columns(1), firstCell.Value)

            'Set the range to be merged, using the Resize method '
            Set rngToMerge = firstCell.Resize(countCells, 1)

            'Disable alerts which will notify you that the cells contain values, only the 1st will be retained.'
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            'et voila!
            rngToMerge.Merge
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

            'reset the firstCell to nothing
            Set firstCell = Nothing

        'proceed to the next unmerged row
        x = x + countCells
        'Do this loop only as long as x is less than the number of rows in our range'
    Loop While Not x >= fullRange.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

**UPDATED**

There were some problems because this data table was a `ListObject` and the table still had `AutoFilterMode = True`, both of prevent the merging of cells. Even on the ribbon, the Merge & Center option is disabled when these conditions are present.

Fortunately, they're both easy enough to fix!

```
Sub SystemSize()

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim I As Long, Groups As Long
Dim rngTable As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rngTable = ws.Range("A2:I" & lastRow)
rngTable.Sort key1:=Range("I2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes 'Sorts data


'## THE REST OF YOUR CODE UNCHANGED GOES HERE ##
'## THE REST OF YOUR CODE UNCHANGED GOES HERE ##
'## THE REST OF YOUR CODE UNCHANGED GOES HERE ##
'## THE REST OF YOUR CODE UNCHANGED GOES HERE ##


ws.AutoFilterMode = False

On Error Resume Next
ws.ListObjects("Table 1").Unlist
On Error GoTo 0

MergeTableRows lastRow

ws.Columns("C:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel won't run through the line: rngToMerge.Merge
and I'm not quite sure why

Comment: Giving you an error? What's the error message? Also, try putting this line above it `MsgBox rngToMerge.Address` let me know what it shows.

Comment: It says application-defined or object-defined error. And the message box says A$2$:A$4$

Comment: If you do it manually, `Range("A2:A4").Merge` does that also give an error?

Comment: Is the worksheet protected? Are the cells already merged? There's a lot of things I think that could go wrong, which I probably can't diagnose without seeing the file.

Comment: Neither of those are happening. Any way I could send the file to you so you could take a look at it?