# How to fix the Merge macro in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that sorts and creates different ranged groups of values. I have a column with Metric Tons Per Hour in it that I sort and it groups any values from 6-8 together and creates a new column naming that group 6-8 MTPH. I do this with 6-8, 10-15, 16-21, 24-28, and 40-48. The problem is it does this header for each row so for every row included in the 16-21 group has a 16-21 MTPH label. I want my code to merge and center all of those cells so it only has one label for each group. The code has a Merge function in it that somebody helped me with but it debugs on .Merge with Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Below is the code I'm using, any help to fix this is much appreciate.

```
Sub SystemSize()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, groups As Long
Dim intStart As Integer
Dim intFinish As Integer

lastRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:I" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range("I2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

groups = 1


Do While groups < 8
 i = 2
    Select Case groups
      Case 1


    For j = 2 To lastRow

        If Cells(j, 9) >= 6 And Cells(j, 9) <= 7 Then

            If intStart > 0 Then
                intStart = intStart
                    Else
                    intStart = j
            End If

            intEnd = j

            Cells(j, 1) = "6-7 MTPH" 'Cells(j, 1)
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    strRangeToMerge = "A" & intStart & ":A" & intEnd

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Range(strRangeToMerge)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    intStart = 0

Case 2


    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 10 And Cells(j, 9) <= 15 Then

            If intStart > 0 Then
                intStart = intStart
                    Else
                    intStart = j
            End If

            intEnd = j

            Cells(j, 1) = "10-15 MTPH"
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    strRangeToMerge = "A" & intStart & ":A" & intEnd

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Range(strRangeToMerge)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    intStart = 0


Case 3

    'Cells(1, 4) = "'16-21"
    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 16 And Cells(j, 9) <= 21 Then

         If intStart > 0 Then
                intStart = intStart
                    Else
                    intStart = j
            End If

        intEnd = j

            Cells(j, 1) = "16-21 MTPH"
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    strRangeToMerge = "A" & intStart & ":A" & intEnd

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Range(strRangeToMerge)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    intStart = 0


Case 4
    'Cells(1, 5) = "'24-28"
    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 24 And Cells(j, 9) <= 28 Then

         If intStart > 0 Then
                intStart = intStart
                    Else
                    intStart = j
            End If

        intEnd = j

            Cells(j, 1) = "24-28 MTPH"
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Next


      strRangeToMerge = "A" & intStart & ":A" & intEnd

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Range(strRangeToMerge)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    intStart = 0

Case 5
    'Cells(1, 6) = "'30-38"
    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 30 And Cells(j, 9) <= 38 Then

         If intStart > 0 Then
                intStart = intStart
                    Else
                    intStart = j
            End If

        intEnd = j

            Cells(j, 1) = "30-38 MTPH"
        End If
    Next


      strRangeToMerge = "A" & intStart & ":A" & intEnd

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Range(strRangeToMerge)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    intStart = 0

Case 6
    'Cells(1, 7) = "'40-48"
    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) >= 40 And Cells(j, 9) <= 48 Then

         If intStart > 0 Then
                intStart = intStart
                    Else
                    intStart = j
            End If

        intEnd = j

            Cells(j, 1) = "40-48 MTPH"
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

      strRangeToMerge = "A" & intStart & ":A" & intEnd

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Range(strRangeToMerge)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    intStart = 0

Case 7
   For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(j, 9) > 0 And Cells(j, 9) < 6 Or Cells(j, 9) > 48 Then
            Cells(j, 1) = "No Group"
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

End Select

groups = groups + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes excel has problems with ranges if they aren't referring to a specific sheet. It's a strange error and there isn't any real documentation on it, but I've had the same problem before. The error comes up because it is calling a range and it doesn't know where it is referencing, since it doesn't default to an active sheet. Try:

```
With Activesheet.Range(strRangeToMerge)
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at your file -- assuming that it is the exact same file that Harris Eldridge emailed me earlier today -- you will see that you can't even merge cells using the ribbon option.

This is because your file contains a table ListObject, which can't be merged. Also, you probably didn't turn off the AutoFilter, which again, can't be merged.

You can turn off AutoFilter, and you can `Unlist` a `ListObject`. I provided the solution here, already.

[Code replaces table headers and will not merge rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593734/code-replaces-table-headers-and-will-not-merge-rows/16596096)

**Please avoid duplicate questions in the future.**